# Syntax error when getting data in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I try to make a simple JSON file get it using XMLHttpRequest.

I've debugged all I observed, but it still can't run, what's the problem here..

```
var getData = function() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "battletheme.json";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var themeinfo = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            showField(themeinfo);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var showField = function(inputcat) {
    var txt = "";

    for(i=0; i<inputcat.length; i++) {
        txt += "Place: " + inputcat.field[i].fieldname + " , Boundary: " + inpucat.field[i].rightboundary + " <br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("msg_box").innerHTML = txt;

}

getData();
```

And the JSON file is here: (It's all in my computer and in the same root)

```
{"field": [
        {"fieldname" : "forest","leftboundary" : 1, "rightboundary" : 500},
        {"fieldname" : "jungle","leftboundary" : 1, "rightboundary" : 600},
        {"fieldname" : "island","leftboundary" : 1, "rightboundary" : 200}
]}
```

Comment: What error do you get? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: you misspelled 'inputcat' here: inpucat.field[i].rightboundary

Comment: @SLaks : yes, but it only shows: "syntax incompatible" on line1, column1 refer to json file. I use Mozilla debug console.

Comment: @trevor : thanks, thats an extra bug..

Comment: Ajax does not work on file:/// in case that is your issue.

Comment: @mplungjan It only works when I upload onto a server?

Comment: Normally yes. Security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try inputcat.field.length instead of inputcat.length (I don't have 50 rep, otherwise I would just have made a comment)

Comment: Thanks! It shows now, but, in the debug console, it always shows "syntax incompatible" on line1, column1 ,but it still work well. why is it...

Comment: Not sure, I got "valid json" when I copy/paste the json into http://jsonlint.com/. You might have some additional syntax validation going on like jshint, jslint.

Comment: Not a problem. I also recommend using http://www.jslint.com/ to get proper feedback on all javascripts idoms and gotchas.